# Struct Properties Cannot Be Identified

Tags: ethereumj

I have been learning Solidity and I have run into a scoping issue with the structs. I thought by default, all properties of a struct are put into storage. When I try to add the battles variable as an argument, it is not identified by the EVM compiler. Why is this? Thanks.

```
struct TargetCoreBase {
uint hp;
uint levels;
uint AlienCount;
uint TargetAliens;
uint LossCounter;
uint WinCounter;
uint battles;
}

TargetCoreBase[] target;

mapping(uint => address) base;

        address owner = msg.sender;

function CreateTarget(string _hp, uint _levels, uint _AlienCount, uint _TargetAliens, uint _LossCounter, uint _WinCounter, uint _battles) internal {
       require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_CoreBaseId));
       uint TargetId =  target.push(TargetCoreBase(_hp, _levels, _AlienCount, _LossCounter, _WinCounter, 0));
       base[TargetId];
    }


string TargetCoreBaseErr = "No CoreBase level";

function CheckTargetPairing(_battles) returns (bool) {
   if(TargetCoreBase.battles = 0) {
       return true;
   }
   else {
       return false;
   }
```

**UPDATE**

I have the right number of arguments now, but the problem still persists. In fact, replacing _battles with any of the other struct variables returns the same result of - "identifier not found".

Comment: Don't you get a `TypeError: Wrong argument count... ` compiler error for the `push()` line? Which would then point you in the direction of flygoing's answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recognized because you're omitting it. Your struct:

```
struct TargetCoreBase {
    uint hp;
    uint levels;
    uint AlienCount;
    uint TargetAliens;
    uint LossCounter;
    uint WinCounter;
    uint battles;
}
```

But when you create an instance of the struct:

```
target.push(TargetCoreBase(_hp,        //TargetCoreBase.hp
                          _levels,     //TargetCoreBase.levels
                          _AlienCount, //TargetCoreBase.AlienCount
                          _LossCounter,//TargetCoreBase.TargetAliens
                          _WinCounter, //TargetCoreBase.LossCounter
                           0));        //TargetCoreBase.WinCounter
                                       //TargetCoreBase.battles is omitted
```

Common sense says that you're actually omitting the `TargetAliens` variable though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on the previous answer...

You've got the following issues:

- Your `push()` call is missing and entry for `battles`, or whichever parameter it is that's missing (as per flygoing's answer).
- `CheckTargetPairing()` doesn't include the type of the `_battles` parameter.
- In `CheckTargetPairing()`, the `if` statement isn't using the parameter you've passed in. It's trying to reference the type declaration, rather than an actual variable.
- The same `if` statement is assigning a value (`=`) rather than making a comparison (`==`).
- `CreateTarget()` has the wrong type for the `_hp` parameter (`string` instead of `uint`).

Here's something that will get you part-way there. I've no idea if the below is actually what you're aiming to achieve, but is the closest representation to what you've provided that compiles.

```
contract YourContract {

  struct TargetCoreBase {
    uint hp;
    uint levels;
    uint AlienCount;
    uint TargetAliens;
    uint LossCounter;
    uint WinCounter;
    uint battles;
  }

  TargetCoreBase[] target;

  mapping(uint => address) base;

  address owner = msg.sender;

  function CreateTarget(uint _hp, uint _levels, uint _AlienCount, uint _TargetAliens, uint _LossCounter, uint _WinCounter, uint _battles) internal {
    uint TargetId =  target.push(TargetCoreBase(_hp, _levels, _AlienCount, _LossCounter, _WinCounter, 0, 0));
    base[TargetId];
  }

  string TargetCoreBaseErr = "No CoreBase level";

  function CheckTargetPairing(uint _battles) returns (bool) {
    if (_battles == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  }
}
```